# Allignment of elements on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Here is my code excerpt

```
 JButton browse,upload;
 JPanel panel;
 JLabel username,path;

 final JTextField  usernameText,pathText;
 final JTextArea statusText;

  InputWindow()
  {
  username = new JLabel();
  username.setText("Username:");
  usernameText = new JTextField(15);

  startDate = new JLabel();
  startDate.setText("Start Date :");
  startDateText = new JPasswordField(15);

  path = new JLabel();
  path.setText("File Path :");
  pathText = new JPasswordField(15);

  browse=new JButton("Browse..");
  upload=new JButton("Upload..");

  statusText = new JTextArea(35, 35);
}
```

How should I add it to `JFrame` or `JPanel` to align it in the folowing ways

1. Row 1 ---> username and username Text
2. Row 2 ---> startDate and startDateText
3. Row 3 ---> path, pathText, browse and upload
4. Row 4 ---> statusText

I always have though time aligning the elements. Please Guide.

Comment: GroupLayout sounds good for your problem: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html

Comment: [all you need - a visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). By combining these virtually all layouts are possible.

Comment: Don't rollback edits, I'm only improving yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way, but the easiest understandable way!

Put everything you want in a row in one JTable, for example:

```
JPanel row1 = new JPanel();

row1.add(username);
row1.add(usernameText);
...
```

And so on! The reason behind that is, if you put them on a JPanel it is easier to place it on a grid. If you have done that, use a GridLayout for you JFrame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(new GridLayout(4, 1));
```

The "4" are the rows and the "1" are the columns! Now you just have to add the JPanels to the JFrame, like:

```
frame.add(row1);
frame.add(row2);
```

Keep in mind that that is not the best solution! There are ways too, where you do not need so much panels. For example the [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) would be the best thing. If you want to see all Layouts, you can do that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I explained that here, because I think that it is the easiest understandable way.